# How to respect case sensitivity on table visual?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following data in an excel file

Sheet Name: Accounts

Data example:

```
Account, Balance
0x100, 500
0X100, 1000
```

Note 1st account has x in small case and the 2nd account has X in upper-case.

I have imported this into Power BI. When I place the Account (col 2) in a Power BI table visual or in a slicer, it only shows 1 row 0x100. So it is treating both accounts as same. Is there any work around to display both?

**For example I want to filter account's that have balance less than 1000.**

Answer (score -1):

Slicers return unique values which is always desired. Why would you display both values? It doesn't make sense at all, because the end user won't know what is what.

In order to solve your problem you should create a calculated column with concatenation of those values.

```
Calculated col = Table[ID] & " - " & Table[Account]
```

EDIT:
I didn't notice that *X* in the second row is uppercased. I believe PBI is always case-sensitive in that kind of situations.

Check the [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/How-to-make-Search-option-as-Case-insensitive-in-Power-BI-slicer/m-p/1507899)

Comment: Power query is case sensitive. Power BI visuals and dax is case in-sensitive.

Comment: @variable Case sensitivity is irrelevant for visuals. The Power BI engine (which is Analysis Services) under the hood is case-insensitive, so the visuals can't do anything about that - when in the visual you ask the engine to get a distinct list, the visual will get the case insensitive version of the distinct values. While Analysis Services in general can be configured to be case sensitive, when you use Power BI (Desktop or Service) or Azure Analysis Services, you have no option to change that.

Comment: So if I want to display list of accounts having balance less than 1000, then how to achieve this (look at my data in the question)?